# Add a common attribute for two entities in ER daigram

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, erd

There is a member who registered under a club. That members has membership for that club. the club continue a news letter. when club send the newsletter and they send only for the main member of the family. when members pay the fees for the club they can pay it by member or family. 
family and member has common attribute called address. 
I want to know how add a common attribute for family and member. family has two task pay the fees and receive the newsletter.[image]

Comment: I suggest you make `address` an attribute of `member` and let it apply transitively to `family`.

Comment: can you explain how add a transilitive attribute

Comment: If family belongs to a member, then there's a functional dependency `family -> member`. If you have an address attribute on member, there's a functional dependency `member -> address`. That gives us a transitive dependency `family -> member -> address`. So if you just add a normal address attribute on member, you can look up the member's address for any given family member.